# How to get information without group on the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get top according to `SUM(d.OrderQty)`, but I need also information according to specific filter (`OrderSourceID`).

When I add it to the group it change the order logic and return multiple lines for same number. What is the correct way to do this SQL?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (@NumOfRecords) 
         i.Number as Number,
         i.Description as Description,
         SUM(d.OrderQty) as TotalCount,
         CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 1 THEN SUM(d.OrderQty) 
            ELSE 0 
         END as TotalSource_1,
         CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 2 THEN SUM(d.OrderQty) 
            ELSE 0 
         END as TotalSource_2,
         CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 3 THEN SUM(d.OrderQty) 
            ELSE 0 
         END as TotalSource_3 
     FROM 
         tblHeader h
     INNER JOIN 
         tblDetail d on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItemDetail id on id.ItemID = d.ItemID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItem i on d.ItemID = i.ItemID
     WHERE
         CONVERT(DATE, h.OrderDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     GROUP BY
         id.ItemID, i.Number, i.Description, h.OrderSourceID
     ORDER BY
         SUM(d.OrderQty) DESC) x
ORDER BY
    x.Number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly then you just need to move the references to h.OrderSourceID inside the SUM, like this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (@NumOfRecords) 
         i.Number as Number,
         i.Description as Description,
         SUM(d.OrderQty) as TotalCount,
         SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 1 THEN d.OrderQty ELSE 0 END) as TotalSource_1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 2 THEN d.OrderQty ELSE 0 END) as TotalSource_2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 3 THEN d.OrderQty ELSE 0 END) as TotalSource_3
     FROM 
         tblHeader h
     INNER JOIN 
         tblDetail d on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItemDetail id on id.ItemID = d.ItemID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItem i on d.ItemID = i.ItemID
     WHERE
         CONVERT(DATE, h.OrderDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     GROUP BY
         id.ItemID, i.Number, i.Description
     ORDER BY
         SUM(d.OrderQty) DESC) x
ORDER BY
    x.Number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (@NumOfRecords) 
         i.Number as Number,
         i.Description as Description,
         SUM(d.OrderQty) as TotalCount,
         SUM(CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 1 THEN d.OrderQty 
            ELSE 0 
         END) as TotalSource_1,
         SUM(CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 2 THEN d.OrderQty
            ELSE 0 
         END) as TotalSource_2,
         SUM(CASE 
            WHEN h.OrderSourceID = 3 THEN d.OrderQty
            ELSE 0 
         END) as TotalSource_3 
     FROM 
         tblHeader h
     INNER JOIN 
         tblDetail d on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItemDetail id on id.ItemID = d.ItemID
     INNER JOIN 
         tblItem i on d.ItemID = i.ItemID
     WHERE
         CONVERT(DATE, h.OrderDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
     GROUP BY
         id.ItemID, i.Number, i.Description, h.OrderSourceID
     ORDER BY
         SUM(d.OrderQty) DESC) x
ORDER BY
    x.Number
```

Comment: it has the same problem. this sql returns the same item (according to  number column) in multiple lines because of the group with OrderSourceID. i need to sum according to OrderSourceID but i don't want the logic to change because of it.
if i add inside the where also to find according to  Number like '11019816' i see 2 lines. i need i line. it also change the select top because it summarize the OrderQty in 2 lines.

Comment: @xdd You moved h.OrderSourceID inside the SUM expression but forgot to remove it from the GROUP BY.